# How to move an arc created in onDraw using drawArc() method to center on screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, paint

I have drawn a circle with an inner radius and outer radius using drawArc() method. I am facing difficulty in making it to the centre of the screen. Currently, with the below code I am getting it near the left corner.

```
public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    final int strokeWidth = 180;

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

   ((Activity)getContext())
    .getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    rect = new RectF(width/2-strokeWidth, height/2-strokeWidth, 
    width/2+strokeWidth, height/2+strokeWidth);

    Shader shader = new SweepGradient(rect.centerX(), rect.centerY(), 
    colours, null);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(225, rect.centerX(), rect.centerY());
    shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    //Initial Angle (optional, it can be zero)
    angle = 0;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, START_ANGLE_POINT, angle, false, paint);

}
```

Comment: See this article: http://shaftdevs.blogspot.com/2016/10/custom-views-awesome-pie-chart.html
I think it will be helpful for you. It shows how to draw the arcs and how to center the drawing area as well.

Comment: @paulina_glab Thank You